# Prevent further action executions

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a list of downloads in a blog-posts. Upon clicking on the link I'm incrementing a downloads `downloadcount` property. In order to prevent further executions I've got this Item-Controller `download`. For some reasons `alreadyIncreased` is always false even on consecutive executions of the actions.
Why is that?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  alreadyIncreased: false,

  actions: {
    incDownload: function() {

      if (this.get('alreadyIncreased') === false){
        this.set('alreadyIncreased', true)

        this.get('model').incrementProperty('downloadcount')
        this.get('model').save()
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This is the template:

```
  {{#each download in post.downloads itemController="base.download" }}
    <p>
      <a {{ action "incDownload"  }}>
        {{ download.name }}
      </a> - {{ download.downloadcount }} Hits
    </p>
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the item in your `#each` loop is being re-rendered (for some reason) and the item controller is being re-created. There's a fairly easy way to test for that, just add this to your item controller class:

```
wasCreated: function() {
    console.log('Item controller created');
}.on('init')
```

This will run every time your item controller is instantiated. With this in place, try clicking on one of the download links and see if it runs afterwards. If it does, then your problem is what I described above.

Personally, I never put persistent state in item controllers for this reason. I generally allow the action to bubble up to the parent controller and put the state there. Or I will wrap the model in a wrapper object and put the state there.

Comment: I'm guessing this is exactly what's happening. I think that when the model underneath the itemController changes, the itemController gets regenerated.

Comment: You are correct.  I work with the object in the parent-controller now which won't get regenerated.